# Почему не рисуется после изменения размеров?

Tags: c#, winforms

Работаю в WinForms. Использую pictureMain ( это pictureBox control ) как место, где я рисую. Изначально оно имеет фиксированный размер, но должно изменяться вместе с изменениями размеров формы, т.е должно растягиваться. После каких-либо изменений размеров формы должен выполниться код ниже.
Но если он выполняется, то рисовать на новой, растянувшей части pictureMain почему-то нельзя ( хотя на старой можно ), как это исправить?

```
private void formResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tableLayout.Width = this.Width;
            tableLayout.Height = this.Height;

            ColorsPanel.Width = tableLayout.Width;

            pictureMain.Width = tableLayout.Width;
            pictureMain.Height = tableLayout.Height - ColorsPanel.Height;

            MessageBox.Show(pictureMain.Width + ":" + pictureMain.Height);
        }
```

Вот код рисования:

```
private void MouseUpMeth(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MouseAlive = false;
        }

        private void MouseDownMeth(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MouseAlive = true;
            Pos_1 = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        }

        private void MouseMouveMeth(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MouseAlive == true)
            {
                Pos_2 = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

                Grah.DrawLine(Pencil, Pos_1, Pos_2);

                Pos_1 = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            }
        }
```

Comment: а где код рисования?

Comment: @Konst Добавил код.

Comment: яснее не стало. что такое Grah ? как вы задаёте контекст рисования? почитайте про Invalidate()

Comment: Рисовать нужно не на PictureBox, а на Bitmap, который установлен ему. Это вы сделали? И по коду все не очень понятно.

Comment: В `formResize` вы изменяете размер `PictureBox` но не картинки (`Image`) внутри него. Попробуйте пересоздать `pictureMain.Image` с новыми размерами и `Graphics` от него (вроде у вас он`Grah`)

Comment: @lancwork Спасибо большое.